# How can I get a phone app on a tablet?

Tags: applications, tablet, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a brand new Galaxy Tab 2 that is apparently not compatible with my bank's tablet app. Someone on another forum mentioned that they just use the phone version on their tablet, but they don't say how they got it. When I go to the google play store, I only see one version. I do have the app on my phone; is there any way to transfer it?

Comment: Try searching on Google Play using your computer. That should show all the results.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, and apparently there only is one version, so I don't know what the other user was referring to.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the app on your phone, you might want to take a look at [AppMonster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.android_telefonie.appmanager). This app allows you to create backups of your apps' `.apk` files to your SD card (the Pro version even can do so automatically each time you install/update an app, so you always have the chance to revert to a previous version if an update breaks something). You can then pick that `.apk` from your SD card, copy it to your tablet, and "side-load" it (i.e. install it manually). For this to work, you must enable "unknown sources" in your tablet's settings (otherwise it only accepts installs directly via the Playstore).

Comment: Not sure I understand. Are you saying I would back it up to my phone's SD card, then move that card to my tablet? Is there a reason I couldn't just copy the .apk to my dropbox online and then copy it from dropbox to the tablet?

Comment: Either way would work. But first you need to get access to the `.apk` -- that's what *AppMonster* is for. Once backed up with *AppMonster*, you can find the `.apk` on your sdcard. Now it's up to you how to transfer it to the other device: copy via computer, via Dropbox, via WiFi direct... whatever suits you best.