# Smartphone App running on Tablet

Tags: applications, tablet

We recently bought an Android Shopping App for Smartphones (supporting 2.2 to current version). Sadly, the app ist not available for tablets.

Is it just a button in the IDE to create a tablet version (not tablet optimized) or is there much more to do?

For example: every iOS iPhone App is running on an iPad (looks ugly, but works)

Comment: I found a lot of related questions and answers, sorry for the duplicate
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36545/how-can-i-get-a-phone-app-on-a-tablet
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/50101/app-compatibility-with-a-tablet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your AndroidManifest.xml and see if you have below prezented:

```
    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" >
    </supports-screens>
```

There is no button for tablets :) you have to make it available for that type of screen.
Hope this helps.

Comment: plus, you need to make layouts for the specific type of screen of course and when the app is rended on the device it knows from what folder to call the view.You can find the same logic with the drawable* folder. You can test your work on emulator, or better yet use Genymotion. The latter is faster and runs with VMWare if i remember correctly.